# How can I have facet items set to disabled instead of hidden if no results?

Tags: views, 8, search

We currently have a Views page with Search API and Elastic Search.

There are 3 facets available:

- Category (radio, single selection)
- Range (checkbox, multiple select allowed)
- Type (checkbox, multiple select allowed)

We want to be able to select a category, e.g. "Fruit" and have Range selected e.g. "1-10", this should "blur out/disable" different Types which have 0 results e.g. if Type had:
 - Box of 24
 - Package of 6
 - Single item

Then perhaps the Fruit for 1-10 would only have type "Package of 6" and "Single item" available, and "Box of 24" would be blurred out (disabled but still shown in the DOM).

How would we achieve this?

Currently the 3 facets use "OR" instead of "AND" as "AND" causes the facet items to be removed from the DOM...

Comment: Are you talking about facets or filters.  By definition facets should only show the options that are available for the current search results.  E.g. if no items have Meat, this will not be an option in the facet.  Exposed filters on the other hand will show all options regardless of search results.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to "blur"? The facets or views results? Are your results grouped and you want to show group titles even where there's no items in it? Can you add a screenshot of what your facets and results look like currently when some range has 0 results?

Comment: @CGMonroe ah, well I want the "filters" for say "Type" which might have 3 different Types... to "blur" or "disable" if that type has no results.

So if I have Type:
- Box
- Package
- Letter

And if I click on "Package", then "Box" would have no results because no Package exists with Letter, so it should show as "disabled/blurred"... but Letter would stay visible so the user can still click "Letter". I suppose I should switch to AND filter but it removes the other types from the DOM instead of showing them as in-active/blur/disabled/additional class...

Comment: @prkos I just want to "blur/disable" the different filter options to prevent the user from seeing "No results found with this search"... I think I probably just need to change the facets to AND but this removes the filters from the DOM.